# Looking for HTML toc generator

Tags: html, tableofcontents

I want to generate toc for the heading tags. Is there any free program?

Comment: What is this "toc" you speak of? Google guesses *"Table of Contents"*, but Wikipedia is confused: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOC . Is this a programming question? What have you tried?

Comment: @Kobi, I'm pretty sure he means table of contents.

Comment: Yes toc=table of contents; common maintenance headache for all html designers

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the `htmltoc` script mentioned by @user5858, there is [`hypertoc`](http://search.cpan.org/~rubykat/HTML-GenToc-3.20/scripts/hypertoc), a more powerful rewrite of the same, again done with Perl. Install it like this (on Ubuntu Linux for example):

```
sudo cpan -f -i HTML::GenToc
```

Use it like this:

```
hypertoc --inline --make_anchors --make_toc --overwrite file.html
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a [blog post](http://grymoire.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/creating-table-of-contents-for-static-web-pages-using-sed-make-and-perl/) on generating table of contents for an HTML page using hypertoc, sed, and make. The shell script also inserts google ads using an ad name. I also created a [navigation section](http://grymoire.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/generating-website-navigation-using-perl-sed-and-make/) that can be used to navigate to other pages on the web site.

The sample template of a web page I use looks something like this:

```
<!-- INCLUDE Navigation -->
<div id="centerDoc">
<h1>Title</h1>
<!-- Insert an ad -->
<!-- INCLUDE GoogleAd1 -->
<!-- Insert the table of contents here -->
<!--toc-->
<h2>More HTML code here</h2>
```

I wrote a script called *include* that reads a file named *.html.in and created a *.html file. The script looks like this. I also used a makefile to convert the *.html.in files into the *.html files

```
#!/bin/sh
#This script modifies HTML pages staticly, using something similar 
# to the "#INCLUDE" C preprocessor mechanism
INCLUDE=${1?'Missing include file'}
shift
IFILE=${1?'Missing input file'}
OFILE=`echo $IFILE  | sed 's/\.in$//'`
# get the name without the path
OFILENAME=`echo $OFILE  | sed 's:.*/::'`
if [ "$IFILE" = "$OFILE" ]
then
    echo input file $IFILE same as output file $OFILE - exit
    exit
fi

ARGS="--toc_entry 'H1=1' --toc_end 'H1=/H1' --toc_entry 'H2=2' --toc_end 'H2=/H2'  --toc_entry 'H3=3' --toc_end 'H3=/H3'  --toc_entry 'H4=4' --toc_end 'H4=/H4' --toc_entry 'H5=5' --toc_end 'H5=/H5'"
# The string !--toc-- is used as a marker to insert the new Table of Contents
TOC="--toc_tag '!--toc--' --toc_tag_replace"
eval hypertoc $ARGS $TOC --make_anchors --make_toc --inline --outfile - $IFILE| \
sed "/<!-- INCLUDE [Nn]avigation/ r $INCLUDE
# Quick and dirty way to add a way to get back to the Toc from an Entry
# 1) put a marker in the beginning of the ToC
    s/<h1>Table of Contents/<h1><a name=\"TOC\">Table Of Contents/
# 2) Add a link back to the ToC from each entry
    s:\(<h[1234]>\)<a name=:\1<a href=\"$OFILENAME#TOC\" name=:g
# Include ad named 'GoogleAd1'
    /INCLUDE GoogleAd1/ {
    r Ads/GoogleAd1
    }
" >$OFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

The [samaxesjs TOC jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/samaxesjs/wiki/TOCPlugin) works pretty well.

Comment: It does not get SEO advantage. That is Bots don't come to know how nicely a page has been outlined in TOC.